# filter global search records

Tags: global-search

I want to filter the Global search box results record. When I search any account from the global search box, only those records will appear whose billing city is not null. How to do it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with global search (i.e. SOSL where we only have control over the `FIND` clause) because we can't specify which fields to look at.

A listview, on the other hand, would be able to filter out specific values (null included) from specific field(s). The drawbacks being that listviews are limited to a single object, it takes a bit more knowledge to create, and the filter values are hard-coded.

The next step after a listview would probably be a report (where the filter values can be changed and the report re-run). Once again, this requires a bit more knowledge to create/modify.